# While parsing annotations could not find MAYBE in enum <none>. Scala + Micrometer

Tags: scala, scalac, micrometer

While trying to use micrometer on a Scala project, I got this warning:

> [error] While parsing annotations in /Users/vargasmontero/.ivy2/cache/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/jars/micrometer-core-1.0.4.jar(io/micrometer/core/lang/Nullable.class), could not find MAYBE in enum .

It was introduced in 1.0.0-rc.8 but I can't see the release in github.

- Sbt 1.1.1
- scala 2.12.5
- micrometer 1.0.4

Comment: Can you explain more about not being able to see the release? Also what does your Scala code look like that has the error?

Comment: A minimal project that has the issue would look like this:
In the build file add as dependency: `"io.micrometer" % "micrometer-registry-datadog" % "1.0.4"`
Then create a trait using Datadog Config:
    trait MicrometerRegistryConfig {  
      val config = new DatadogConfig() {  
      override def apiKey(): String = "123"  
      override def step(): Duration = Duration.ZERO  
      override def get(key: String): String = null  
      }  
    }

Comment: i have the same warning but I can't tell if it's causing a problem or not

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Scala 2.13.2, [configurable warnings](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8373) can be used to suppress this nuisance with

```
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++=
  Seq(
    //<other options omitted>

    // warnings
    "-Wconf:msg=While parsing annotations in:silent"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much expertise on Scala but looking into it a bit, Scala doesn't seem to ignore missing meta-annotated classes when it's used on return types (it seems okay when it's used on parameters) unlike Java. Micrometer's `@Nullable` implementation is the same as the implementation of the Spring framework. So if you use `StringUtils.quoteIfString()` from the Spring framework, you will see the same warning.

It's a warning, not an error, so you can simply ignore it or if it bothers you, you can add the following optional dependency as a workaround:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.2" % Optional
```

Someone who is a Scala developer might give you a better advice.

FTR this is copied from https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1133#issuecomment-452434205.

---

#### UPDATED

I missed the "error" part. You seem to have "-Xfatal-warnings" compiler option.

Comment: This does not suppress the "While parsing annotations..." warnings.